# Efficient way to compose a SparseArray from system of linear equations

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I have several relations between some variables, e.g. `id[1] - id[2] = 0, id[2] = 0`. I need to compose a SparseArray that contains the coefficients. In that example,`{1,-1},{0,1}`. But I have several thousand terms and my method takes almost 1h. I use a `Do` loop and I imagine Mathematica has a more efficient way.

Any suggestion or help is extremely welcome.

Minimal example:

```
nmax = 10000;
list = Table[{RandomInteger[{1, 10}]*id[RandomInteger[{1, nmax}]] + 
     RandomInteger[{1, 10}]*id[RandomInteger[{1, nmax}]]}, {j, 
    nmax}];
Do[list[[j]] = list[[j]] /. id[n_] :> id[n, j], {j, Length[list]}]; (*<- too slow*)
SparseArray[
 list /. Plus -> List /. a_. id[n__] :> ({n} -> a) // Flatten]

(*Time:2.5s*)
```

Comment: Generation of the initial list already takes half of final computation time. I think you have to look at SymmetrizedArray[ ] if you want to impose symmetries in an efficient way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What takes time in my machine is the Do loop. Generating the first list takes only 0.04s, but anyway that I already have in my real case.

Comment: Check document of `CoefficientArrays`

Comment: Thank you for this. `CoefficientArrays[list, id[#] & /@ Range[1, nmax]][[2]] // Transpose` does the same as my function in 0.023 s.

Comment: But testing I discovered that the bottleneck was in reassigning elements of list: `list[[j]] = list[[j]] // ....` . Simply doing `newlist = list` and `nlist[[j]] = list[[j]] // ...` speed it up to 0.048s

Answer (score 8):

You can add indices to your matrix instead of doing iteration and then a simple `Replace` can do all the work.

Assuming:

```
nmax = 10000;

list = Table[{RandomInteger[{1, 10}]*id[RandomInteger[{1, nmax}]] + 
     RandomInteger[{1, 10}]*id[RandomInteger[{1, nmax}]]},
   {j, nmax}];

(* list: {{id[5] + 4 id[6]} , ... } *)
```

Solution:

```
Block[{temp},
  
  temp = 
   ArrayPad[list, {0, {0, 1}}, Transpose@{Range[Length[list]]}];
  
  (* temp: {{id[5] + 4 id[6], 1} , ... } *)

  r2 = SparseArray@
    Replace[temp, {
       {m1_.*id[v1_] + m2_.*id[v2_], i_} :> Sequence[{v1, i} -> m1, {v2, i} -> m2],
       {m_.*id[v_], i_} :> ({v, i} -> m)
    }, {1}]
  
  ]
```

If we store your solution's result in `r1`, you'll see `r1 == r2` and the calculation is ~**60 times** faster (`3.49` vs `0.057` on my computer).

Comment: Thank you so much. I had tried to reduce everything to a simple replace but didn't succeed. This is very clever. However the bottleneck was simply in `list[[j]] = list[[j]] //...` (see the comments below the question)

Answer (score 7):

You may use "MapIndexed" for this task. This command takes every sublist of list and applies a function to it. This function receives as first argument the sublist and as second element its position.

We first define the function that transforms expressions like: num1 id[num2] into {row number, num2} -> num 1, needed to create the sparse array:

```
fun[sub_, pos_] = sub /. { n1_?NumericQ : 1  id[n2_] :> {pos[[1]], n2} -> n1, Plus -> List };
```

With this we apply SparseArray to the list to create the definition of the array:

```
sa = MapIndexed[fun, list] //Flatten;
SparseArray[sa]
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool. Mathematica has so many useful functions like this. The bottleneck of my function was actually somewhere else, but thank you so much for your solution